# Minimum value of $\sum_{1\le i \lt j \le 2022} a_ia_j $

Tags: summation

Hello how can I find the minimum value of $$\sum_{1\le i \lt j \le 2022} a_ia_j $$ Where $ a_i $ and$  a_j $  are -1 or 1?

My thought was that the number of -1 and 1 (so 1011 -1's and 1011 1's) should be same but I'm not sure if that is right.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Where is this from? The presence of $2022$ (or $2021$ in the title) makes me think that this is a contest problem.

Comment: @anomaly Sorry my mistake. I changed the question a little (The orginal being from a book). The original question stated the least non negative value (which I know the answer for that) but I was wondering if I could find the minimum even if it is negative.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer simply be when all the terms are $-1$?

Comment: @Lorago Won't that be maximum since all terms are 1?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I just misread the question

Comment: Expand the product $\left(\sum a_i\right)^2$.

Comment: @anomaly I solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$ (\sum_{i=1}^{2022} a_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{2022}a_i^2 \; + 2\sum_{1\le i<j \le 2022} a_ia_j $$

Since $a_i^2$ is always $1$,

$$ \sum_{1\le i<j \le 2022} a_ia_j = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{2022} a_i)^2 -2022}{2}$$

The minimun of $(\sum_{i=1}^{2022} a_i)^2$ is $0$, therefore the minimum of $\sum_{1\le i<j \le 2022} a_ia_j$ is $-1011$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the sum be $x$. Then $2x+\sum a_i^2=(\sum a_i)^2$. Since $\sum a_i^2=2022$, you need to minimize $|\sum_{i=1}^{2022} a_i|$. The minimum is $0$ and is achieved iff $1011$ of $a_i$ are $1$ and the other $a_i$ are $-1$. Hence the minimum of $x$ is $(0-2022)/2=-1011$.